# Excel RATE function to calculate interest rate on unknown payments

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, rate

Excel function RATE is as follows;
RATE(nper,pmt,pv,fv,type,guess)

how do I get it to work if I don't know the repayments, but do know the start and end values?

loan starts at say $150,000, ends at $0
period is 300 months.

how can I get the interest rate?

Comment: yes, the repayments would be equal instalments, at end of each month.

Comment: You will only be able to work out the rate if you can split the loan and the interest. e.g the loan is worth $130,000 and the total interest is $20,000. A loan of $150,000 which goes to $0 in 300 months implies equal repayments of $500 a month but you're just paying back the loan, not the interest.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense now, how would I calculate it if the loan is $150,000, but what I have paid total is $170,000 which is including the interest?

Comment: The total period is 300 months

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that you receive $150,000 now in respect of 300 payments at the rate of $566.67 per month the parameters for [RATE](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Rate-Function.html) are:

```
nper   - The number of periods over which the loan or investment is to be paid.
pmt    - The (fixed) payment amount per period.
pv     - The present value of the loan / investment.
[fv]   - An optional argument that specifies the future value of the loan / investment,  
         at the end of nper payments. If omitted, [fv] takes on the default value of 0.
[type]  - An optional argument that defines whether the payment is made at the start or  
          the end of the period. The [type] argument can have the value 0 or 1, meaning:  
          0 - the payment is made at the end of the period;
          1 - the payment is made at the beginning of the period.
          If the [type] argument is omitted, it takes on the default value of 0  
          (denoting payments made at the end of the period).
[guess] - An initial estimate at what the rate will be.
          If this argument is omitted, it will take on the default value of 10% (=0.1)
```

So say in order in cells from A2:F2:
`nper` is 300
`pmt` is -170,000/300 ie ~-566.67 (entered as `=ROUND(170,000/300,2)`)
`pv` is 150,000
`fv` is 0 (the default)
`type` you have not specified, but likely the default (0)
`guess` I have taken as 1% (ie .01)

```
=RATE(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2)
```

returns `.085%`. This is the rate per period (ie per month) and would normally be expressed per year, usually by multiplying by 12, i.e. to give 1.02% per year. It is not quite the same as 1.02% when paid annually at the end of each year but the monthly compounding of such a low rate makes no significant difference to two decimal places of percentage.

It is an effective interest rate of 1.0248% that yields a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_interest_rate) (second definition) 1.02% over twelve equally spaced, equally sized installments, as may be calculated with:

```
=NOMINAL(1.0248%,12)
```

The above may be checked at a site such as [TimeValue Software](http://tcalc.timevalue.com/all-financial-calculators/personal-finance-calculators/loan-rate-calculator.aspx?LOANAMOUNT=%24150%2C000.00&DOWNPAYMENT=%240.00&PAYMENTAMOUNT=%24566.67&TERM=300&TERM_UNITS=Months&SHOWAMORTIZATIONSCHEDULE=on&COMPUTE=COMPUTE&CALCULATORID=PC07&HIDEFORMTAG=TRUE&TEMPLATE_ID=www.timevaluecalculators.com_1&PostBack=true#results) which even offers the full repayment schedule (though with a rounding error - of less than $1).